# ExecuteSprocAccessor how to return string from stored procedure?

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 5, set up the Database successfully but am now facing the following problem.

I have a stored procedure which is a simple select statement which returns 1 string (not an output parameter).

In code I wrote:

```
var result = _db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<string>("GetTypeOfPerson", mapper, parameters);
```

However this won't work as string does not have a parameterless constructor. Any way around? Or how can I call with Enterprise Library the stored procedure and obtain my result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that indeed won't work out. Do the following instead:

```
var result = _db.ExecuteScalar("GetTypeOfPerson", parameters);
```

That'll give you exactly one result back.

Comment: That works out for me. Thanks a lot! I will mark it as the answer once this site lets me to.

Comment: as per microsoft this method is retired http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748712.aspx , what is the current alternate?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have the same problem, in my case i retrieve a list<string>, if i use List<string> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<string>(SP_NAME, param).ToList<string>(); does not work.